# Array: Compare values from API with values from own database

Tags: php, mysql

I have built a list (moviesSeen) where people can save their seen movies.

Now I want to get the director for each movie from an API and then compare which movies have already been seen. The output of the movies works without problems, but I can't get the result from the database (moviesSeen) to match the movies of the director. How can I achieve this?

The goal of the script is to show all movies of a director and mark all the ones you have already seen.

```
function getCrewDetails() {

    global $apiKey;
    global $language;

    $personID = htmlspecialchars($_GET['personID']);

    $url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/" . $personID . "?api_key=" . $apiKey . "&" . $language . "";// path to your JSON file
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $personPrivate = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col">';
    echo '<img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/' . $personPrivate->profile_path . '" class="img-thumbnail">';
    echo '</div>'; // end div col

    echo '<div class="col-8">';
    echo '<h1>' . $personPrivate->name . '</h1>';

    if (!empty($personPrivate->biography)) {
        echo $personPrivate->biography;
    } else {
        echo '<p>Verdammmt! Zu dieser Person liegen keine biographischen Details vor.</p>';
        echo '<p>Dabei hätte sie es doch so verdient :(</p>';
    }

    echo '</div>'; // end div col
    echo '</div>'; // end div row

    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($person);

    $url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/" . $personID . "/movie_credits?api_key=" . $apiKey . "&" . $language . "";// path to your JSON file
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $personCareer = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

    echo '<div class="container mt-4">';
    echo "<h2>Filmographie</h2>";

    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-sm">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Film</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Gesehen</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Funktion</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';

    echo '<tbody>';

    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM movieSeen WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $row ) {
        echo $row['movie_id'] . ', ';
    } // output of the saved IDs in movieSeen

    foreach ($personCareer->crew as $showCrewDetails) { //Output of the movies
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><a href="getMovie.php?movieID=' . $showCrewDetails->id . '">' . $showCrewDetails->title . ' ' . $showCrewDetails->id . ' (' . substr($showCrewDetails->release_date, 0, 4) . ')</a></td>';
            echo '<td><span class="badge badge-danger">Movie Seen</span></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $showCrewDetails->job . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';

    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';

    //echo '<pre>';
    //var_dump($personCareer);

}
```

I know that I have to edit the last foreach loop, but I just can't get it to work :(

Comment: You prepared and executed the query, but you don't seem to have fetched the results. `$films = $stmt->fetchAll();` or similar.

Comment: @droopsnoot The result of the IDs from movieSeen are stored in `$row['movie_id']`. I do not know how to compare it with `$showCrewDetails->id` in the last foreach loop.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, sorry. So that variable is the same as your `$row['movie_id']` from your local database? For each movie in the last loop, you need to see if that ID is contained in your array from the previous query. You could use something like array_search() for that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: I will try this. Thank you!